# Debug Assertion Failed: file reading in C using CLion

Tags: c, debugging, clang, clion

This is the code that was provided as starter code on which I have to answer a couple of question using the data provided in `data.txt` file. `data.txt` is kept in the same folder as my code and contains line separated words all of which are of length 21. I am familiar with C but I do not know anything related to files and file management.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(void) {
    char* fname = "data.txt";
    FILE *fptr = NULL;
    char line[20000][22];
    int i = 0;
    fptr = fopen(fname, "r");
    while(fgets(line[i],20000,fptr))
    {
        line[i][strlen(line[i]) - 1] = '\0';
        i++;
    }
    printf("Read a file with %d lines.\n",i);
}
```

When I run this code in CLion, the following error appears.

[image: error image]

I am using LLVM clang compiler. The same error appears even if I use Microsoft Visual Studio compiler. It would be helpful if you can explain what the error means and how to resolve it!

Comment: Looks like you want `char line[22][20000];` rather than  `char line[20000][22];`. Also you should check that your file does not contain more lines.

Comment: If you just want to count the number of lines, not actually use the contents of the file, then read character by character, and keep a "newline" counter which is increased when you read a newline. If you still want to use `fgets` then you don't need an array of arrays, just a single array for the line. You also should check that `fopen` doesn't fail, you don't need to remove the ending newline, and please name your counter variable something more descriptive (like `line_count` or similar).

Comment: @EugeneSh. No, `line[22][20000]` would only accommodate 22 words each having maximum length of 20000 characters. I have checked, the file indeed contains exactly 20000 lines each line containing a single word of length 21. Also, this code runs on repl.it but doesn't run on my machine

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The print statement is just for sanity check

Comment: With `fgets(line[i],20000,fptr)` you read *up to* `20000` characters into an array of only 22 characters (null-terminator included).

Comment: @Harshil Then you are not using it correctly. `fgets(line[i],20000,fptr)` will read up to 20000 characters into a *single* `line[i]` - which it is obviously doesn't have space for (it has space for 22).

Comment: By the way, have you *read* the error message? The crash seems to happen inside `fgets`, and the problem is seems to be that `stream.valid()` fails. Are you sure that you opened the file? What does `fopen` return? Maybe its time to add some error checking in your code?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I replaced the 20000 in fgets with 22. Same error is popping up

Comment: "each line containing a single word of length 21". You have forgotten the newline. Array size needed is `21 + 1 + 1 = 23`.

Comment: ... use `while(fgets(line[i], sizeof line[i], fptr))` **and** check `i` stays within bounds. Input has a nasty habit of not conforming to your expectations.

Comment: Have you changed the array dimension to `23` as advised? Be bold: try `char line[21000][30];`. Also, you are assuming that the last character is a newline: [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input/28462221#28462221) is bullet proof.

Comment: @WeatherVane Your calculation of array size 23 seems to be correct. `fgets(line[i], 23, fptr)` on replit doesnt throw an error. However, CLion still doesnt work